Remove Specific MSMQ Message
Message message = mq.Peek
if (message != null)
  {
    message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter (new string[]{ "System.String,mscorlib"});
    string messageBody = message.Body.ToString ();
    if (messageBody != null)
      {
        if (messageBody.Contains ("ErrorFile"))
          {
            using (MessageQueueTransaction transaction =
                   new MessageQueueTransaction ())
            {
              if (mq.Transactional)
                {
                  transaction.Begin ();
                  message = mq.Receive ();
                  //message = mq.ReceiveById();
                  transaction.Commit ();
                }
            }
          }
      }
  }

I am trying to read the message from MSMQ and if I found specific matching message I am trying to remove from queue, but facing issue is it only removing body from the message and leaving behind empty message in MSMQ.
instead using Peek() in that place if I use Receive() method I can able to remove message from queue but it will remove all messages irrespective of any matches but I don't what that.
I need a solution only to remove matching specific message from the queue permanently without leaving any empty message in the queue.

Why do you think a Receive is "leaving any empty message in the queue."?  Can you post a short, complete repro if the behavior?

Sorry not understood what you said, Can you just elaborate what I need to do?

Write a short program to first send a few messages, and then receive a single one from the middle.  If that doesn't help you figure out the issue, post the code as part of your question here.
